# Adding a custom .bst to TexMaker in Windows

Tags: bibtex, miktex

In order to get the required bibliography style for my dissertation, unable to find a correct one, I used `makebst` to create a custom one. However, I find myself unable to use it, my program just says:

```
This is BibTex, Version0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit) 
The top-level auxiliary file: Doktorarbeit.aux I couldn't 
open style file freiburg.bst ---line 26 of Doktorarbeit.aux: 
\bibstyle{freiburg:}I'm skipping whatever remains of this 
command I found no style file--while reading file Doktorarbeit.aux 
(There where 2 error messages
```

I have googled a lot and have not found a correct explanation for my setup. I use Texmaker and Windows 7.

Comment: just put freiburg.bst in the same folder as Doktorarbeit.tex and it should work

Answer (score 0):

If you would rather not have the .bst-file in the same directory or if you would like to use it for more than one document, create a custom root directory. In MiKTeX, for example, this can be done in the MiKTeX Options: Go to the *Roots* tab and click on *Add...*. To have some consistency, I usually use the original root paths within my custom root directory, i.e. `<myroot>\bibtex\bst\base` in this case. Finally, execute the following command `initexmf -u -v` (short for `initexmf --update-fndb --verbose`) from the command line (navigate to the \miktex\bin directory of your distribution - in case you are using MiKTeX) to update the name database.